# how can i add Authorization : "JWT <token>" to http request ? in Nuxt.js

Tags: jwt, authorization, nuxt.js, bearer-token, nuxt-auth

I am developing with Nuxtjs and using nuxtauth.

I am trying to give the content " JWT  " to the Authorization of http request.

However, even if I change the string to be given by coding, "Bearer " is sent and I get a 401 error.

[image: failed call mypages API]

The formed text (including the JWT) can be seen in the console.

[image: expected header]

The process is as follows.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="getUserInfo">get user data</button>
    <div>
      {{ responseData }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pretoken: this.$auth.strategy.token.get(),
      responseData: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getUserInfo() {
      const url = "/server/v1/mypages/";
      const pretoken = this.pretoken;
      const fixedtoken = pretoken.replace("Bearer", "JWT");
      console.log(fixedtoken);
      this.$axios.setHeader("Authorization", fixedtoken);
      this.responseData = await this.$axios.get(url);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where are you call the http request?

Comment: @hoangdv Oops! I had removed the code for debugging purposes, then updated the post.
Sorry, and thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Search `Bearer` keyword in the whole project. I guess you have an axios interceptor somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the codes below and it should work

```
const config = { headers: { 'Authorization': fixedtoken } };
this.responseData = await this.$axios.get(url, config);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that method and it did not work. The Authorization of the request was still   Bearer < token >...
I checked the config in the console, but it shows headers: {Authorization: "JWT <token>"} and I don't know why :_(

Comment: @dore, try adding this option to your `auth/nuxt` configuration. `auth: {
  token: {
    global: false,
  }
}`, using `$axios` sends your token automatically and might be overwriting yours. I hope it works for you.

Comment: This is an absolute solution!
However, to be precise, it worked correctly in my environment when I set Nuxtconfig as follows
`auth:{ strategies:{ local:{ token: { global: false, }, ...... } } }`
Thanks to you, I can move ahead with development! Thank you so much!